# Efficiently generating samples from an urn with maximum per element constraint?

Tags: performance-tuning, random, combinatorics

I need to sample from a distribution that is a hybrid of uniform and hypergeometric in the sense that all elements are sampled uniformly *until an element reaches some specified maximum observations*, upon which that element will no longer be sampled.

Think of it as an urn with some $N$ distinctly colored balls, and I sample with replacement $M$ times, but any time a ball has been observed $O$ times in a sample, it is not replaced.

A quick-n-dirty implementation is:

```
genoutcomes[src_, max_, len_] := 
  Module[{oc = {}, cnt = ConstantArray[max, Length@src], rc, r = Range@Length@src},
   Do[oc = {oc, src[[rc = RandomChoice[Unitize@cnt -> r]]]};
    cnt[[rc]]--;, len];
   Flatten@oc];
```

For example, if the urn has 3 differently colored balls, I want to sample 6, with a maximum observation limit for any ball of 2,

```
genoutcomes[{red, green, blue}, 2, 6]
```

produces such a sample.

I'd like to get a more efficient mechanism for doing this (pure Mathematica - I can write it in C or Lisp or whatever, but I'm not after that), ideally for multiple samples in bulk vs calling a routine once per sample.

The above is as I said a quick-n-dirty sketch, I'm pondering but it's late and Morpheus is calling, figured it's an interesting puzzle to throw out here....

Edit: From interactions with posters, here's a quick sanity check for testing.

Generating a large batch of results for 3 elements, 5 max, 9 sample length (something like `res = Table[genoutcomes[Range@3, 5, 9], 1000000]` for my routine, substitute yours), the result of

```
Count[res, #] & /@ {{x_, x_, x_, x_, x_, ___}, {___, x_, x_, x_, x_, x_}}
```

should have a ratio of ~5:1.

Comment: You made some comments below demonstrating that proposed solutions are wrong. Could you please post the code that you use for the verification and demonstrate that your own solution passes the test (CC @bobbym)

Comment: @yarchik - no need for code, simply generate a large sample of results, using e.g. `Table` and check the distribution.

Comment: It can be I misunderstand your question, for instance why the sum of probabilities should be not unity, but 1/27 + 2/81 + 4/243=19/243. If you would like to get help, a more precise formulation would be appreciated.

Comment: @yarchik - those are the probabilities, as clearly stated in the comment, of the possible cases for 4-runs. Why on earth would you think they should sum to 1? Your answer creates samples where *all* states are equiprobable - clearly, this is not the case for such a sampling scheme. I don't really know how I could make the OP or comments any more clear.

Comment: I am sorry, I wanted to help. I still do not understand how to compute your numbers. Maybe I can learn if you provide one more example. For instance, what probabilities do you expect for genoutcomes[{red, green, blue}, 4, 8] ?

Comment: @yarchik That should have probabilities 1/27, 2/81, 4/243, 8/729, 193/17496 respectively for a state with a 4-run (4 consecutive of the same element) starting at positions 1,2,3,4, and 5 respectively. In other words, {red,red,red,red,blue,blue,green,green} is *much* more probable (>5x) than {blue,blue,green,green,red,red,red,red}. Your routine does not, for obvious reasons, produce this distribution. Were you to remove the `DeleteDuplicates`, it gets closer with larger samples, but then why bother, better to just generate them in the first place. Make no mistake, I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Ok, I see. It looks like a typical application for Dynamical Programming. I guess the ultimate goal is to compute some expectation values, not just generate very large ensemble. For this, one needs to sample the whole tree, as I mentioned in my answer, transition probabilities being dependent on the vertex.

Comment: Is this from a Project Euler problem?  It feels eerily familiar, and I can't think of another context in which I would have worked on this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Certainly not. Project ciao.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard @ciao In looking at this I ended up creating a function where the number of coloured balls can vary and the samples with replacement limit can vary per ball colour.  It gets the correct ratio on for a sample size of 10,000.  However, it takes 3-times as long to run than the `genoutcomes` above.  In any case, if there is interest I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This approach is quite different from my previous answer. Therefore I decided to separate them for clarity.

Let us write first a function that for a given sample returns the probability to obtain it via the random process described in the original post.

```
prob[ncol_, max_, len_, conf_] := 
  Module[{cnt = ConstantArray[max, ncol], ucnt, p = 1},
   Do[
    ucnt = Unitize@cnt;
    p = p ucnt[[conf[[i]]]]/Total[ucnt];
    cnt[[conf[[i]]]]--;, {i, len}];
   p];
```

Taking example given above we generate 10 samples:

```
a = Table[genoutcomes[Range@3, 5, 9], {10}]
(*{{2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1}, {3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1}, {3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}, {3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1}}*)
```

and compute the corresponding probabilities

```
prob[3, 5, 9, #] & /@ a
(*{1/19683, 1/19683, 1/19683, 1/3888, 1/19683, 1/5832, 1/5832, 1/19683, 1/8748, 1/19683}*)
```

So far so good. For small `max` and `len` one can now generate all possible configurations and assign the probabilities, and the problem is solved. But what if the number of configurations is huge? I guess for their brute force generation the function in the OP is almost unbeatable. But we rarely need just configurations. Most probably the ultimate goal would be to *compute or compare probabilities of certain classes of configurations*. Here, I can provide an analytical result.

For illustration, let us consider the example above. For `max=5` and `len=9` we want to analytically compute the probabilities of following outcomes:

```
{{x_, x_, x_, x_, x_, ___}, {___, x_, x_, x_, x_, x_}}
```

This can be accomplished with the following code:

```
p1 = prob[3, 5, 9, #] & /@ (Join[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, #] & /@ 
     Tuples[Range[3], 4]) // Total
(*1/243*)
p2 = prob[3, 5, 9, #] & /@ (Join[#, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}] & /@ 
     Tuples[Range[3], 4]) // Total
(*16/19683*)
```

The ratio of probabilities is as requested

```
p1/p2
(*81/16*)
```

i.e., close to 5.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Finally I found time :)

Answer (score 1):

I did

```
genoutcomes[src_, numberforeach_, draws_] := 
RandomSample[Table[src, {numberforeach}] // Flatten, draws]

genoutcomes[{red, green, blue}, 10, 30]
```

yields

{red, blue, green, red, red, red, green, blue, green, blue, red, red, \
red, green, green, red, green, red, green, blue, blue, green, blue, \
green, blue, red, blue, green, blue, blue}

Hope I did not miss the point of the exercise.

Comment: This does not generate a proper distribution. For example, genoutcomesLSC[{1,2,3},4,6] should generate a 4-run for leading/middle/end of sample with probabilities 1/27, 2/81, 4/243 respectively. This routine makes such runs equiprobable. Don't fret, I've been pondering this, as have some *seriously* sharp posters here, this is one of those simple-but-hard problems.

Answer (score 1):

Three observations:

- Your random process is non-Markovian, i.e. depends on the previous
  steps
- The number of states is finite, in your example there are only 90 of 
  them.
- In view of (i) and (ii) you have a random walk on a tree.

You can build the tree explicitly for small systems and study it. But you can also use a brute force approach based on your existing method.

1) generate all states

```
 config = Table[genoutcomes[{red, green, blue}, 2, 6], {1000}] // 
DeleteDuplicates
```

2) Verify that the length is as expected, (notice a rather large sampling ---1000):

```
Length[config]
(*90*)
```

3) Generate any big number (let say 4) of samples

```
RandomChoice[config,4]
```

**Follow up**

After OP clarifications it is evident that in such a method every transition between the neighbouring tree vertices is equiprobable. To deviate from this assumption the whole tree needs to be traversed keeping account of probabilities. Let us see what can be done here ... (continuation follows)

Comment: This does not generate a correct distribution. See comment on other answer for details.

Comment: @ciao But I use your code :) Then it is your code that is wrong ...

Comment: you might want to rethink that....

Comment: @ciao Perhaps, when more information of what is "correct" is provided in the question. I guess you assume that DeleteDuplicates considers permutations.

Comment: I tried working on this and came down to the tree thing, but I couldn't think of any way to handle that short of brute force enumeration.  There should be a lot of symmetry to exploit for optimization since every ball may be observed the same number of times but I failed to find the way.  I look forward to seeing what you come up with!

Comment: I am still hoping you find time to work on that continuation.  At the same time I understand if you do not, or have lost interest.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It is in fact time, or rather its lack, not lost of interest for me :) But I do hope to do it soon.